# Which SVN command shall I use to to switch revision of checked-out working copy?

Tags: svn

I work in git so not so sure about SVN.
I checked out revision 15000 inside a folder c:\svn\code which I suppose has the working copy.

Which SVN command should I use to switch to previous revision 14000 in the same working copy folder c:\svn\code ?

Answer (score 1):

The same command ([`svn update`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)) with the same option, but with just different value

`svn up -r14000`